# How can I improve the performance of my Neural Networks?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, neural-network, gpu

As I am learning to write Neural Networks with Python, I have just written the following linear association network that takes in `K` input vectors `x_1, ..., x_K` of respective length `L` and `K` output vectors of respective length `N` and finds optimal weights using gradient descent.

As the calculation times explodes really quickly when adjusting `K`, `L` and `N`, I was searching on how to speed this up. I discovered cupy, but cupy is much, much slower than numpy in this case. **Why would this be**? When changing the code to the cupy variation, I do nothing but substituting every `np` to `cp` as I imported cupy as `cp`.

I have also used `f = njit()(ManyAssociations.fit)`, but then I had to `return W` in fit instead of writing `ManyAssociations.weights = W`. **Is there any way to use njit inside of the class or apart from that is there a better way to use numba/cuda**? It turns out to be much quicker after "warming up" with a first function call, but it still reaches its limit at with vectors of the mentioned shapes around `K = L = N = 9`.

**What are some other good ways to speed up code like the below one? Could I be writing more efficiently? Could I be using the GPU better?**

```py
import numpy as np

class ManyAssociations:
    def fit(x_train, y_train, learning_rate, tol):
        L_L = x_train.shape[1]
        L_N = y_train.shape[1] 
        W = np.zeros((L_N, L_L)) 
        
        for n in range(L_N):
            learning = True
            w = np.random.rand(L_L) 
            
            while learning:
                delta = (x_train @ w - y_train[:,n])
                grad_E = delta @ x_train
                w = w - learning_rate * grad_E

                if (grad_E @ grad_E) < tol: 
                    W[n] = w 
                    learning = False      
    
        ManyAssociations.weights = W

    def predict(x_pred, W):
        preds = []
        for k in range(x_pred.shape[0]):
            preds.append(W @ x_pred[k])
        return np.array(preds)
```

Comment: You can try using [JAX](https://github.com/google/jax). It has a numpy-like API with automatic differentiation and GPU support.

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example, otherwise people won't be able to help you.

Comment: @jakub Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it turned out that JAX does not support Windows yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I discovered cupy, but cupy is much, much slower than numpy in this case. Why would this be?

Computations on GPU are split into basic computationally-intensive building-blocks called *kernels*. The kernels are submitted to the GPU by the CPU. **Each kernel call take some time**: the CPU has to communicate with the GPU and often use the relatively slow PCI interconnect (both should be synchronized), allocations should be made on the GPU so that resulting data can be written, etc. The CuPy package transform each basic Numpy instruction to a GPU kernel naively. **Since you loop executes a lot of small kernels, the overhead is huge**. Thus, if you want you code to be faster on GPUs using CuPy, **you need either to work on huge chunk data or to write directly your own kernel** (this is hard since GPU are quite complex).

> Is there any way to use njit inside of the class or apart from that is there a better way to use numba/cuda?

You can use **`@jitclass`**. You can find more information in the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/jitclass.html).

Moreover, you can take advantage of **parallelism** to speed you code up. To do that, you can for exemple replace `range` by `prange` and add the property `parallel=True` to Numba's `njit`. You can find more information [here](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html).

> What are some other good ways to speed up code like the below one? Could I be writing more efficiently? Could I be using the GPU better?

Neural networks are generally very computationally intensive. Numba should be quite good to get reasonably high performance. But if you want a fast code, then you will either need to use higher-level library or to get your hands dirty by rewriting what the libraries do yourself (likely with a much lower-level code).
The standard way to work with neural networks is to **use dedicated libraries** like TensorFlow, PyTorch, Keras, etc. AFAIK, the former is flexible and highly optimized although it is a bit low-level than the other.